# TreeSet<Entry<Character, Long> sort using comparator problem

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparator, treeset

I want to Sort a TreeSet in Java 11.
I tried using a comparator, but the problem is lambda expression does not consider args as Entry.

I wanted to do this:

```
SortedSet<Entry<Character, Long>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(map.entrySet(), 
    ((o1, o2) -> (int) (o1.getValue() - o2.getValue())));
```

but the problem is there's no such constructor in TreeSet. So I tried another procedure:

```
SortedSet<Entry<Character, Long>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(map.entrySet())
    .comparator()
    .compare(o1,o2)
```

compare method needed parameter:

```
compare(capture of ? super Entry<Character, Long> o1, capture of ? super Entry<Character, Long> o1)
```

but I don't know what arguments I have to pass instead of o1,o2.

Comment: o1.getValue() AND o2.getValue() ???

Comment: @nafas o1 and o2 didn't define in this scope. compare method gives two args: 
compare(capture of ? super Entry<Character, Long> o1, capture of ? super Entry<Character, Long> o1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there is no constructor to do it all at once, doesn't mean you can't do it in 2 lines.

```
SortedSet<Entry<Character, Long>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Entry::getValue));
sortedSet.addAll(map.entrySet());
```

Comment: Or let `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` create Comparator like `new TreeSet<>(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create set first

```
SortedSet<Entry<Character, Long>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> (int) (o1.getValue() - o2.getValue()));
```

and then add elements

```
sortedSet.addAll(map.entrySet());
```

There is no way to set comparator after `TreeSet` is created.

PS: Comparing values using `-` is bad idea. You better use `Integer.compare` or create comparator using `Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)`.

Comment: While that solves OP's issue, beware of comparing numbers with just a minus operator. There can be overflow errors, especially considering you're casting a long result to int. Better compare with Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)

Comment: @talex do not use `minus` for the comparator; there is `Long::compare`

Comment: @kumesana Yes, will add note.

Comment: @kumesana best to use `Comparator.comparingLong(Entry::getValue)`

Comment: @jbx I wouldn't care which to use. Why do you think it's better?

Comment: Well implementation-wise they will probably be equivalent. But `comparingLong` shows intent more clearly, since the indication that `getValue` is a `Long` is further away in the declaration so not that readable.

Comment: @jbx Not convincing to me, but if it is to someone else, great.

Comment: @kumesana Maybe I value readability more ;). I checked the code of `comparingLong` and it actually uses `Long.compare()` while `comparing` uses the `compareTo` provided by the actual class. Slight difference in implementation, probably no material performance difference.

Comment: @jbx it's not just readability. The intent is to sort the entries, not to ensure that what we compare them with is long. And comparing is shorter than comparingLong, which in absence of other benefits is better for readability. It's more a matter of taste.

Comment: @kumesana The intent is to compare the entries. But you don't know how they are being compared. `comparingLong` clearly indicates that it is using the natural ordering of `Long`. If I just wanted to make lines shorter I would name variables `a`, `b`, and `c`... shorter lines doesn't mean readable.

Comment: @jbx when you're deciding you want to sort the entries, you don't care that what you're comparing them with is long. For instance, if suddenly you were using String ids to be sorted lexicographically, or LocalDateTime for timestamps instead of Long, there is no reason to change anything in that part of your code.

Comment: @kumesana Of course you do. What if you wanted them descending. You chose to sort by that field so you care exactly what sorting method you are applying.

Comment: @jbx it's using natural comparison, and if you want it descending you can take the descending natural comparison. It's usually a straightforward reasoning. Again, more a matter of taste.